# Javascript will not run, using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a small project, trying to build a simple snake game.
However, my javascript will not run. I have passed a lot of code in the file, but somehow it only runs the index.html file. I have looked at the debugger in Mozilla and it finds the javascript.

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to CSnake50</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="playHUD">
            <h2 id="scoreboard"> Length </h2>
        </section>

        <section id="gameOver">
            <h1 class="title">GAME OVER!</h1>
            <h3 id="restartButton">Restart?</h3>
        </section>
        <canvas id="game-screen"></canvas>

        <script src="snake.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[Image when running Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDUcb.png)

Comment: have you called the function from your js file?

Comment: So it never entered your mind that "_JavaScript will not run_" might require a bit of JavaScript code to look at in order to determine where the issue **in the JavaScript** might be? Please share a bit of JS.

Comment: You'd need to post the contents of snake.js and style.css, too, better yet, you put everything online together with Index.html.

Comment: Please provide us with more details on ```snake.js```!